# Leaky_Relu in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I'm trying to use Leaky_Relu layer in caffe and can't really figure out where to define it. From the layer definitions [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html), I can see that ReLu has an optional parameter called negative_slope which can be used to define a leaky_relu but I can't figure out where this negative_slope parameter goes into.

The ReLu definition looks like this:

```
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

I tried doing this but it threw me an error:

```
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  negative_slope: 0.1
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As defined in the documentation, **negative_slope** is a parameter. And parameters are defined in the following way. Try This:

```
layer {
   name: "relu1"
   type: "ReLU"
   bottom: "conv1"
   top: "conv1"
   relu_param{
      negative_slope: 0.1
   }
 }
```